# Import FFMPEG Library to Android

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

First, I'm new in this Import thing

I've compiled latest version of ffmpeg with NDK r14b,
and managed to get some Library after compiling(like **libavutil.so,libavcodec.so,libavfilter.so,etc**)

[Click here for pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCMc3.png)

but im a bit confused importing it to my android project.

First, I want to make an **Audio editing app** that can ***merge several mp3 file at specific time***, and ***adjust volume (Increase or Decrease its sound) mp3 file***.

I've read about ffmpeg recently, since most people recommended to use this Library.

For merging :

-https://superuser.com/questions/1092291/merge-many-audio-files-with-specific-positions/1092346#1092346

For adjust volume :

-[Decode MP3, then increase the audio volume, and then encode the new audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496031/decode-mp3-then-increase-the-audio-volume-and-then-encode-the-new-audio)

What i want to ask is:

-from guardian's ffmpeg project and WritingMinds ffmpeg lib (can't post the link since i got not enough rep and this 2 are often mentioned in stackoverflow), does this 2 Libraries have what i needed? I'm a bit confused in this thing. An explanation would be a help.

-from http://ffmpeg-android.blogspot.co.id/ i cant run the ndk-build command at the last part. How should i use it?

Thank you in advance!